# Dell Monitor blacking out

Tags: display, dell-optiplex

Black stripes start appearing on my Dell monitor occasionally and things come back to normal in few minutes. I have tried using a different VGA cable and even power cable but no luck. I doubt if it is a software/driver issue since at times it happens even while the machine starts booting and on my both operating systems - Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I didn't notice any issues related to the display in the Windows Event viewer either.

Here are two photos of the issue -

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical TFT screen's Driver IC that is in end of life... if you want to keep your screen, you can order that electronic board and replace it.

Note that this can also be caused by your computer's video card, an other machine is required to test the screen with.

[image]